# Calculate uncertainty of linear regression slope based on data uncertainty

Tags: regression, uncertainty

How to calculate uncertainty of linear regression slope based on data uncertainty (possibly in Excel/Mathematica)?

Example:
[image: Example plot]
Let's have data points (0,0), (1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8), ... (8, 16), but each y value has an uncertainty of 4. Most functions I found would calculate the uncertainty as 0, as the points perfectly match the function y=2x. But, as shown on the picture, y=x/2 match the points as well. It's an exaggerated example, but I hope it shows what I need.

EDIT: If I try to explain a bit more, while every point in example has a certain value of y, we pretend we don't know if it's true. For example the first point (0,0) could actually be (0,6) or (0,-6) or anything in between. I'm asking if there is an algorithm in any of the popular problems that takes this in account. In the example the points (0,6), (1,6.5), (2,7), (3,7.5), (4,8), ... (8, 10) still fall in the uncertainty range, so they might be the right points and the line that connects those points has an equation: y = x/2 + 6, while the equation we get from not factoring in the uncertainties has equation: y=2x + 0. So uncertainty of k is 1,5 and of n is 6.

TL;DR: In the picture, there is a line y=2x that's calculated using least square fit and it fits the data perfectly. I'm trying to find how much k and n in y=kx + n can change but still fit the data if we know uncertainty in y values. In my example, uncertainty of k is 1.5 and in n it's 6. In the image there is the 'best' fit line and a line that just barely fits the points.

Comment: If you have uncertainty in your $x$'s, you generally shouldn't use ordinary linear regression because it's biased (though small uncertainties will result in small bias; maybe you don't care so much). Are the uncertainties in your y's always constant or do they vary? How are you fitting your line?

Comment: I'm mainly asking about uncertainty in y's. But I'd be happy if the solution would consider uncertainty in x's as well.

Generally they aren't constant, but a solution that requires them to be constant would be fine as well, I tried fitting with linearfit, fit, findfit in mathematica and linest (and a custom function that I found that weights values by uncertainties) in excel.

Comment: Can you explain as clearly as possible how the "uncertainty" values would be related to what would happen under say a repeat of the experiment? i.e. what, precisely, do these uncertainties represent?

Comment: Err for example if y is weight, but the digital scale is only accurate to +-6. (Not the best example with these values, but for example when scale shows 255g it could be 255.0 or 255.9)

Comment: Could you explain how that would relate to the first sentence of my question please?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand you, example would be measuring density, where you would have volume on x axis and weight on y axis.

Fast example: Let's say real weights are 11.63, 23.267, 34.9. But our bad scale can only show with +-5 accuracy, so it shows 10, 20, 30. (Volumes are 1*V0, 2*V0, 3*V0). If we try to fit with a program, it will show density of 10/V0 and 0 error. But the real value is 11.7.

Comment: What I am asking about is that I am trying to identify your model (in the probabilistic sense) for what the numbers we get (both the observations and the uncertainties) are, in the sense that if the whole experiment were repeated (but with the same $x$'s), what the distribution of the observations might then be.

Comment: As I said, if done exactly the same the measurement would be the same. The real weights 11.63g, 23,265g and 34,9g would still be measured as 10g, 20g, 30g.

Comment: So these uncertainties are instead some kind of truncation/bias? Is there any other consistency to their behavior? (say, if I measured an object of say 11,62g would I also be certain to get 10g?)

Comment: "If you have uncertainty in your x's, you generally shouldn't use ordinary linear regression because it's biased" could this be elaborated on? What if there's an expected underlying linear physical model? Why don't the answers (particularly the sampling method) take it into account for determining the uncertainty in the slope and intercept?

Answer (score 10):

Responding to "I'm trying to find how much $k$ and $n$ in $y = k x + n$ can change but still fit the data if we know uncertainty in $y$ values."

If the true relation is linear and the errors in $y$ are independent normal random variables with zero means and known standard deviations then the $100(1-\alpha)$% confidence region for $(k,n)$ is the ellipse for which $\sum (k x_i + n - y_i)^2/\sigma_i^2 < \chi_{d,\alpha}^2$, where $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of the error in $y_i$, $d$ is the number of $(x,y)$ pairs, and $\chi_{d,\alpha}^2$ is the upper $\alpha$ fractile of the chi-square distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom.

EDIT - Taking the standard error of each $y_i$ to be 3 -- i.e., taking the error bars in the plot to represent approximate 95% confidence intervals for each $y_i$ separately -- the equation for the boundary  of  the 95% confidence region for $(k,n)$ is $204 (k-2)^2 + 72n(k-2) + 9n^2 = 152.271$.

[image]

Comment: Is there an analytic result when using a uniform distribution for uncertainty?

Answer (score 5):

I did a naive direct sampling with this simple code in Python:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pylab
def uncreg(x, y, xu, yu, N=100000):
    out = np.zeros((N, 2))
    for n in xrange(N):
        tx = [s+random.uniform(-xu, xu) for s in x]
        ty = [s+random.uniform(-yu, yu) for s in y]
        a, b = np.linalg.lstsq(np.vstack([tx, np.ones(len(x))]).T, ty)[0]
        out[n, 0:2] = [a, b]
    return out
if __name__ == "__main__":
    P = uncreg(np.arange(0, 8.01), np.arange(0, 16.01, 2), 0.1, 6.)
    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(P[:, 0], P[:, 1], bins=(50, 50))
    pylab.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low', aspect='auto',
                 extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```

and got this:
[image: Histogram of direct sampling results]

Of course you can mine the `P` for the data you want, or change the uncertainty distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same hunt before and I think [this](http://vizsage.com/other/leastsquaresexcel/) may be a useful place to start. The excel macro function gives linear fit terms and their uncertainties based on tabular points and uncertainty for each point in both ordinates. Maybe look up the paper it is based on to decide if you want to implement it in a different environment, modify, etc. (There is some legwork done for Mathematica.) It seems to have good walk-through documentation on the surface but haven't opened up the macro to see how well annotated it is.