# Calculate uncertainty of the slope when dependent variable in a linear regression has substantial error?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, error-propagation

I have a dataset in which the dependent variable (y) has known and substantial error, and yet the observations happen to line up quite well along a line when plotted against the independent variable (x). Fitting a linear regression seems to substantially overestimate the precision of the slope estimate for y vs. x.

How can one appropriately propagate the known error in y through to the estimate of the slope?

I think there is part of an answer here, but it assumes the point fit a linear regression exactly: [Calculate uncertainty of linear regression slope based on data uncertainty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70629/calculate-uncertainty-of-linear-regression-slope-based-on-data-uncertainty)

As a reproducible example in R:

```
# the data
set.seed(5)
dat <- data.frame(x = 0:8, y = seq(0,16, length.out=9)+rnorm(9, 0, 0.5), y.se = 3)

# fit a naive model, not considering error in y
mod <- lm(y ~ x, dat)
summary(mod)
preds <- predict(mod, se.fit = TRUE)

plot(dat$x, dat$y, ylim=c(-7,22))
arrows(dat$x, dat$y-1.96*dat$y.se, dat$x, dat$y+1.96*dat$y.se, length=0)

# plot the confidence interval on the linear regression
polygon(c(dat$x, rev(dat$x)), c(preds$fit+preds$se.fit, rev(preds$fit-preds$se.fit)), col = 'grey')
```

[image]

The slope is estimated very precisely near 2.0:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.04670    0.32783   0.142    0.891    
x            1.97546    0.06886  28.689 1.61e-08 ***
```

Visually, however, a slope as low as 0.7 or as high as 3.3 would still fit through the error bounds of y quite well.

Comment: since the line goes through the observations so nicely maybe the error is overestimated?

Comment: In this case, the error is not overestimated. Thanks.

Comment: you can easily repurpose your code example to simulate different slopes (like bootstrapping) to see that the uncertainty should be very small. it is **extremely** unlikely for your experiment to produce a slope of 0.7 or 3.3

Comment: One must be clear about the difference between [mean-response and predicted-response errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_and_predicted_response). The variance of a mean response estimate is determined by the coefficient covariance matrix, giving the confidence bands you show. Many cases or a wide span of `x` values can counterbalance high variance in individual `y` values and give precise slope estimates, implicit in the answer from @user347168. The variance of predicted response for a single new case adds to that the MSE for `y`. That's more related to what your vertical bars show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled with structural equation modelling (SEM)

```r
library(lavaan)

code = '
yhat ~ x     # Latent variable predicted by x
yhat =~ 1*y  # y is the single indicator of yhat
y ~~ 9*y     # y has error variance of 9 (3^2)
'

fit = lavaan(code, dat)
summary(fit)
```

```
lavaan 0.6-7 ended normally after 3 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                          1
                                                      
  Number of observations                             9
                                                      
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                24.572
  Degrees of freedom                                 1
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  yhat =~                                             
    y                 1.000                           

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  yhat ~                                              
    x                 1.975    0.387    5.101    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .y                 9.000                           
   .yhat              0.000
```

Plots can also be useful...

```
library(semPlot)
semPaths(fit, what = 'path', whatLabels = 'est', layout = 'circle2')
```

[image]

Comment: Could you point me towards some background reading on this approach? It looks promising.

Comment: I think I learned about this from [Kaplan's book](https://methods.sagepub.com/book/structural-equation-modeling), but [this blog post](http://reifman-sem.blogspot.com/2012/04/we-recently-discussed-how-to-handle.html) might also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your problem actually is. If there's random error in *y* but not *x*, the regression of *y* on *x* will be unbiased. The uncertainty due to the error will be properly reflected in the standard error of the parameter estimate.

In your example, the *y.se* variable is only used to draw the "arrows" in the graph. It's not used to calculate *y*, so it's not reflected in the **lm** results. Your *y* and *x* are almost perfectly correlated (*r*>.99), so one can predict the other almost perfectly.