# How put uncertainty shading on a linear fit

Tags: linear, uncertainty

I have a scatter plot and only my y values have uncertainty.

I obtained a linear fit to my data (using `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize`).

[image]

I also have the 1 sigma uncertainty for the gradient and the intercept of the linear fit:

Gradient: -4.304e-06 +- 3.908e-06
Intercept: 0.068 +- 0.005

But I want to put some kind of uncertainty shading on my linear fit so i can visualize the uncertainty on the linear fit?

To do this, I think I need to considered the covariance between the gradient and intercept parameters, but I'm not certain. [The top answer on this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70629/calculate-uncertainty-of-linear-regression-slope-based-on-data-uncertainty) gives a formula for the interdependence of gradient and intercept:

[image]

To get my visualization, would I just sample from this ring and plot many linear fits on my plot to shade an uncertainty region?

Comment: 1. Are you after an interval for the position of the line across the x's, or are you fixing some point (e.g.  taking $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ as a given) so you can focus purely on the *gradient* (i.e. specifically on the slope parameter) given the fixed point? I'd normally assume the former for an interval around a fitted line in a picture like yours, but you took the trouble to specify *gradient* in your question, so it's best to be doubly sure) 2. If you're after a *pointwise* interval\*, this is a pretty standard weighted-regression problem and there's an algebraic formula, no need to sample.

Comment: \* by this I mean that the coverage properties would be given pointwise, the coverage statement applying at any specific $x$ value.

Comment: Thanks Glen. Yes I meant the former. I will edit my question to say "uncertainty on the linear fit" instead of "uncertainty on the gradient".

Comment: Assuming you're after a pointwise interval, isn't the CI for the weighted line (available as a simple algebraic formula, though possibly adjusted to z's rather than t's for known error variance if you want to rely on the specific values rather than their relative sizes) doing what you seek?

Comment: Thank you Glen. Yes perhaps I am over complicating this. The confidence interval for the weighted line is indeed what I am looking for. I perhaps can't see the wood for the trees, but which simple algebraic formula do I need?

Comment: For additional discussion and generalizations, please search our site for [regression confidence band](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+confidence+band+formula).